# Python environment management (devel/release)

Tags: python, development-environment, production-environment

I have released a package within my workplace; it is used by ~10 people. I have a very quick develop/test/release cycle (sometimes twice a day), and I am starting to suffer from an increased disorder in my environments. I want to manage this environment with tools such as `virtualenv` and `setuptools`, but I don't seem to get where I want.

For instance, I want to use a "test" database on development, but release to the "real" database. Something along the lines of:

```
if env == "devel":
 dbpath = "/path/to/devel.db"
if env == "release":
 dbpath = "/path/to/real.db"
```

Similarly, I have several configuration files with different parameters for development and release (today I forgot to change one, and I mailed the entire team dozens of emails!).

I want the code to remain clean and separated, so I would prefer not to code a solution like the one presented above.

So, **how would you create a workflow to manage this?** I would prefer not to rely on environment variables and `__file__` statements (but maybe I should?).

Apologies. I know this is not a very clever question, but I want to use the tools at my disposal in a reliable way.

Comment: Whats wrong with __file__ ? )

Comment: @Mike Ramirez: I guess nothing is wrong with it, but it seems too dependent on the folder structure. What if I change from ``/sw/conf/`` to ``/allconf/conf/``? Then I have to update all ``__file__`` calculations. I think I would prefer to give a path.

Comment: if you put the `__file__` calculations in one spot then any move will just be one change. maybe as a DEBUG variable?

Comment: `MYPROJROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))`  Then export MYPROJROOT to be used by the rest of the system. One calculation, done in the root of the project, never needs to be updated.

Comment: @Mike: For the project root I actually do what you suggest. However, the databases and configuration files are not in locations dependent on project root (we check the software in a "managed by root" location and put what we can edit in other folders).

Answer (score 2):

> I would prefer not to rely on environment variables and **file** statements (but maybe I should?).

You should.

You should use three things.

1. Environment variables.
2. Configuration files.
3. Command-line parameters.

Just like every other command-line program.

If this is am imported module, not a program, then it should have NO configuration of any kind.   All of the scripts which import your module must provide **all** configuration as arguments and parameters

There are no circumstances under which an imported module should have a configuration of its own.

Comment: It is not a command line program, it is a module that the users import in Python (many modules, actually) to handle tasks within their own scripts.

Comment: I'm inclining toward an "environment.conf" file as per your point (2).

Comment: @Arrieta: If it's configurable by other scripts, then it should have NO configuration.  The script which uses your module **must** provide **all** configuration as arguments and parameters.